# What is && and || in bash?

Tags: bash, boolean-logic

I am trying to understand following pice of code:

```
for f in *.out; do sort -cg <$f &>/dev/null && res="sorted" || res="unsorted"; echo "File $f is $res."; done
```

For loop iterates through all `.out` files and gives each one as a parameter to `sort`, and the output of the sort is redirected into "nothing". But can someone explain what: `&& res="sorted" || res="unsorted"` does?

Answer (score 6):

A command after the `&&` will only be executed if the previous command exited with a 0 (zero) status code. The other `||` works in the opposite way - a command after a `||` will only execute if the previous command exited with a non-zero exit code.

Here is a small example:

```
cat /some/file/that/is/missing && echo 'Found the file!' # doesn't print 
cat /some/file/that/is/missing || echo 'Unable to find the file!' # will print
```

With the first line, the `echo` command will not execute since the `cat` command failed (because the file doesn't exist)

With the second line, we WILL see the `echo` command because the `cat` command failed.